# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}' in here on line 3

Tags: php, regex

```
function validText ( $input, $min = null, $max = null )
{   
    if ( !empty($min) && !empty($max) ) {
        $text = "^[a-zA-Z\s0-9]{$min,$max}+$";
    } else {
        $text = "/^[a-zA-Z\s0-9]+$/"; 
    }

    if ( preg_match( $text, $input ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

whats the problem ?
sorry newbie problem

Comment: hollsk i think its not a regex problem, but i dont know, anyway thanks for retag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the line:

```
$text = "^[a-zA-Z\s0-9]{$min,$max}+$";
```

The problem is that `{$var}` is a special syntax in PHP.  So `{$var,$var}` is invalid since `$var,$var` is not a valid variable name...

Try this:

```
$text = "^[a-zA-Z\s0-9]{{$min},{$max}}+$";
```

Answer (score 1):

somehow i figure it out :) thanks .

```
function validText ( $input,$min = null ,$max = null )
{   
    if(!empty($min) && !empty($max)) {
        $text = '^[a-zA-Z\s0-9]{'.$min.','.$max.'}+$';
    } else {
        $text = "/^[a-zA-Z\s0-9]+$/"; 
    }

    if ( preg_match( $text, $input ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line

```
"^[a-zA-Z\s0-9]{$min,$max}+$"
```

In strings enclosed in double quotes (`"these"`), you can include variables like `"this = $value"`.

The clean way to do this, especially when including array elements, is enclosing them using `{}`, like `"This is an array element: {$array['element']}"`

Since you have a string containing `"{$something`, php expects this to be a variable and looks for `}`, but sees the `,`. Hence the error.

This will solve the problem:

```
"^[a-zA-Z\\s0-9]{{$min},{$max}}+\$"
```

since the first `{` will not be interpreted as starting a variable to include.

(yes, the `\` and `$` are special as well and need to be escaped)

Answer (score 0):

I think php is trying to evaluate your string because you have used double quotes.  Try using single quotes instead, and concatenating your variables as needed:

```
if ( !empty($min) && !empty($max) ) {
    $text = '^[a-zA-Z\s0-9]{' . $min . ',' . $max . '}+$';
} else {
    $text = '/^[a-zA-Z\s0-9]+$/'; 
}
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Answer (score 0):

PHP interprets variables in double quoted strings. See [String Parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsingunexpected) in the PHP-Documentation.
`{$min,$max}` gets interpreted as the beginning of a variable. And as in PHP `,` in variablenames are not valid it is `unexpected`.

To fix your problem Change this line:

```
$text = "^[a-zA-Z\s0-9]{$min,$max}+$";
```

To this:

```
$text = "^[a-zA-Z\s0-9]{" . $min . "," . $max ."}+$";
```

Answer (score -1):

in PHP double quote strings process escape sequences, so it is probably tripping up on the `\s` inside there. change it to `\\s` (to escape the backslash and make it a literal backslash).